# Common Ground across SCR and Diode Bridge

Tags: motor-controller, bridge-rectifier, thyristor, scr

I am trying to use a common ground to enable a regulated output across the circuit, however as you can see the SCRs and Bridge use the common earth to relay the positive channel in the bus..

Is this the common pattern of connecting this or is there a more stable circuit which could be used?

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly ordinary half controlled bridge. It's only drawback is the amount of noise generated in switching the thyristors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJqatF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is a common way of controlling the amount of DC power delivered by a rectifier. Regulation is accomplished by varying the firing angle of the thyristors.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the best type of EMC Filtration? and where would you put it?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a blog. If you have more questions please feel free to post them as another question.